# How can i modify select in jsp html using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

[image]

I want **Etat** to be like this (inline):

[image]

here is the code of the select jsp

```html
<td>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><%=df.getEtatdemande() %></label>
    <select class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" id="monselect" name="etatdemande">
      <option value="null">NULL</option>
      <option value="ACCEPTER">ACCEPTER</option>
      <option value="REFUS">REFUS</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using bootstrap 4. Try to use `form-inline` instead of `form-group`

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="exampleInputEmail1"><%=df.getEtatdemande() %></label> 
  <select class="custom-select" aria-describedby="emailHelp" id="monselect" name="etatdemande">
     <option value="null">NULL</option>
     <option value="ACCEPTER">ACCEPTER</option>
     <option value="REFUS">REFUS</option>
   </select>
</div>
```